# Responsive "checkerboard" div's - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have to make a checkerboard homepage with several div's containing pictures and text.
I made something like this : 
[image: My homepage]

In the CSS, all blocks are placed with an absolute position and some top, left properties (in px).

The design is correct, but I want to make all this responsive, but in 2 different ways :
1 - Adapt all the body to the screen and eventually increase the font-size property.
2 - Simply align all the blocks in two or one column(s) (for smartphones for example)

I don't want an answer with a ready-made code, just help to realize the responsive version of my homepage.

Comment: You can use jquery masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: i will check this , thanks

Comment: welcome!. please up vote my comment if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into using a CSS framework rather than relying on absolute positioning, which is difficult to adapt for use with multiple screen sizes and make responsive.

Although there is a learning curve when first attempting to use a CSS framework, it quickly pays dividends, especially when taking into account cross-browser and responsive-design considerations.

Probably the most popular CSS framework is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which is responsive by default, and would make producing your layout relatively simple.

Another good option for a CSS framework is [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

There are countless others. Here's a list: http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html

Comment: I forgot something in my post.
This code is for a prestashop homepage using a module to create some HTML page. I don't know if I can use the bootstrap of Prestashop.

Comment: Sure You can use the bootstrap. It's only for the responsive html. Then you can change it into the prestashop template if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I used to realize the responsive with the float columns and change the columns' width through media query. But in your job, you should change the hope wrapper's width and reset the columns' left and top through js. You can consult the plugin '[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)', which may help you.